# Angular 2 transpiled with tsickle can't be processed by google-closure-compiler

Tags: angular, typescript, google-closure-compiler, bundling-and-minification, tsickle

I have an `Angular 2` typescript project that I would like to bundle into one JS file. Bootstrapper:

**main.ts**

```
import {platformBrowser} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from '../aot/dev/app/app.module.ngfactory' //generated code
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory).catch(e=>console.error(e));
```

I used `Angular 2`'s Ahead-of-Time compiler to generate `ngfactory.ts` files.  I then ran [`tsickle`](https://github.com/angular/tsickle/blob/master/README.md) to transform my files into Google Closure Compiler compatible JS. This completed without difficulty:

```
"node_modules/.bin/tsickle" -- -p ./
```

Here is the result:

**main.js**

```
goog.module('C_.websites.learn.angular2.dev.main');var module = module || {id: 'C:/websites/learn/angular2/dev/main.js'};
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
var platformBrowser = platformBrowser; /* local alias for Closure JSDoc */
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/dev/app/app.module.ngfactory';
var AppModuleNgFactory = AppModuleNgFactory; /* local alias for Closure JSDoc */ //generated code
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
var enableProdMode = enableProdMode; /* local alias for Closure JSDoc */
enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory).catch(function (e) { return console.error(e); });
```

Finally, I use [`google-closure-compiler-js`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js/blob/master/README.md) to create a gulp task that bundles all JS into one file.

**gulpfile.js**

```
const closureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler-js').gulp();
gulp.task('closure-compiler', function() {
    return gulp.src('./dev/main.js')
        .pipe(closureCompiler({
            compilationLevel: 'SIMPLE',
            warningLevel: 'VERBOSE',
            outputWrapper: '(function(){\n%output%\n}).call(this)',
            jsOutputFile: 'build.js',
            createSourceMap: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
});
```

The task fails immediately with many errors. Here is a sample:

> dev\main.js:3 (JSC_REFERENCE_BEFORE_DECLARE)
>   Variable referenced before declaration: module$contents$C_$websites$learn$angular2$dev$main_platformBrowser
>
> dev\main.js:5 (JSC_REFERENCE_BEFORE_DECLARE)
>   Variable referenced before declaration: module$contents$C_$websites$learn$angular2$dev$main_AppModuleNgFactory
>
> dev\main.js:7 (JSC_REFERENCE_BEFORE_DECLARE)
>   Variable referenced before declaration: module$contents$C_$websites$learn$angular2$dev$main_enableProdMode
>
> dev\main.js:10 (JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY)
>   Property bootstrapModuleFactory never defined on ?
>
> dev\main.js:3 (JSC_INTERNAL_ERROR_UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)
>   Internal Error: TypeCheck doesn''t know how to hanle IMPORT
>
> dev\main.js:3 (JSC_INTERNAL_ERROR_UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)
>   Internal Error: TypeCheck doesn''t know how to handle IMPORT_SPECS
>   ...

I'm using the latest `tsickle` source cloned from GitHub as of Oct 10, 2016, along with `"google-closure-compiler-js": "^20160916.0.0"`.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: There is more to it than this, but closure compiler doesn't handle named imports such as `@angular/platform-browser`

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Thanks. According to the Angular team itself, `tsickle` transpiles Typescript to closure-compatible Javascipt; checkout [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VnV7R4Ncwc) from 23:18 to 24:18

Comment: I'm extremely familiar with the process and project. I can tell you hands down that the module rewriting process of closure-compiler won't handle that import statement. However I'm not close enough to the tsickle project to answer the question fully or even hint at what needs changed to make it work.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth ok thank you. Does this mean that the import needs to specify a specific file?  Is there a way to set paths as in SystemJS config, so closure knows that `@angular/platform-browser` means `node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js`?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth or, more simply, is there a way to tell closure to use node's module resolution algorithm as `typescript` does when you set `"moduleResolution": "node"` in tsconfig

Comment: Not yet - it's something we want to add soon, but the compiler can only handle paths right now.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth A few months have passed since this post was updated, so I'm wondering if this is possible now. If not, how are people managing to get some angular2 apps through closure?

Comment: @edybourne support for node module resolution was released today: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Releases#february-18-2017-v20170218